# How can I estimate the risk difference confidence interval with the standard errors of the risks?

Tags: confidence-interval, absolute-risk, risk-difference

I have two risks estimated from imputed data, so I cannot say I have a1 events in the exposed and a0 events in the unexposed, as each data set is different. The output of the function are risks and standard errors. How do I find the confidence interval for the difference of the two risks?

Comment: Do you know the sample size?

Comment: yes I know the sample size